# DWH - Incremental Data import

Tags: database, etl

I am designing  a new ETL process , the ETL process should take data from Source DB to Target DB .
The ETL process should run once a day .
My problem here is, how to check the delta and to do incremental import
i cannot perform full import once a day because of the performance issue.
in order to have correct data at the target i have to check the LastUPDATE column for every records that i already have on the target DB because the existing records on the source can be updated  and can be different from yesterday to today .

The solution that i thought about is to take all the key's that i have on the target  and search the same key's on the source and then to compare the lastUPDATE value where the date will be different at the source in front of the target i will delete the record at the target and i will perform new insert .

i have thousand of records and every time it's become bigger and bigger which means it will take more time to run the process.

Any idea how to do that kind of process more efficient ?

Comment: Do your source system tables not have a column that shows when the records were last updated? You can use this to extract all records that have been updated since the last ETL extract

Comment: Hey yes I do have last update date column on source it means that  I have to check for all my records on target the last update date in front of the source for the same records . It will impact the run time of the process so I thought there is some other way

Comment: That's the standard ETL process: take the delta from your source, use those records to look up the corresponding records on your target and insert/update on the target depending on whether matching records were found. Why do you think you need to check all your target records? You're only checking the records that match your source delta

Comment: Hello , let’s say I have 10 record that I just imported to the target during the day 8 records out of 10 were updated I don’t know which columns were update but I do know that the LastUpdateDate column was update and now the date on the source is different from the target this is my indicator to do delete and insert in order to aligned with the source and of course to take the records that I not took yet from the source. Now the question is when I have big amount of data let’s say every day thousands of rows being added eventually the process will be too heavy ? Thnx for the answer :)

Comment: You need to size your platform to handle the volume of data that you have to process. Many companies process 10s (or even 100s) of millions of records per day using processes like this. If you have 1 million records that have changed or been added in a day then you need to process those 1 million records - there is no solution that would somehow allow you to process less than these 1 million records and still reflect all the new/updated records in your target,

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information!!